# jQuery - How to create a basic API condition for audio player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an audio player, and the documentation provided the following API information:

```
jQuid('.playerclass').HeyNow('play'); // for when playing is active
jQuid('.playerclass').HeyNow('pause'); // for when paused
```

How would I write something basically saying..."when the 'play' action is activated, apply a class.

This what I have so far but it doesn't work at all (I'm a javascript newb):

```
jQuid('.playerclass').HeyNow('play') {
    $('.playerclass').addClass("hidebackground");
};
```

Comment: What exactly are `jQuid` and `HeyNow`? Which library is that from?

Comment: It's a script from Code Canyon, wish I could link to the actual script: https://codecanyon.net/item/tiny-music-player-html5-audio-w-flash-backup/6888180

Comment: Right now your code block inside `{...}` doesn't actually have any relationship  to the line before it. Maybe you can pass it as a callback function, but it would depend on the details of the API you're using: `jQuid('.playerclass').HeyNow('play', function() { $(this).addClass("hidebackground"); });`

Comment: Why not just use an `<audio>` element?